# Qual framework devo utilizar em Testes Funcionais no .net?

Tags: .net, testes-funcionais

Gostaria de saber as opções de framework que simula `testes unitários` para o [.net](/questions/tagged/.net).
Conheço um pouco de `Ruby` e sei que nele existe o `Cucumber` que por sinal é muito bom, porém para `.net` fiz uma pesquisa e percebi que existem várias opções. Estou na dúvida, qual utilizar?

Comment: Onde estão os comentários pelos votos negativos?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo esta é uma boa pergunta, gostaria de saber também de saber os motivos pelos votos negativos

Answer (score 5):

### Minhas opções

Você pode usar o `MSTest` juntamente com um framework de Mock como o `Moq`, e algum framework de inversão de controle, tal como o `SimpleInjector`... dessa forma seu sistema poderá ser testado facilmente.

Existem outras opções, mas eu pessoalmente uso esta configuração.

### Outras opções

**Testes:**

- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) (já usei, acho muito bom)
- [MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) (Microsoft, já usei, bom também)

**Mocks:**

- [Rhino mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) (já testei)
- [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) (já usei... muito bom, muito símples)

**Inversão de controle:**

- [SimpleInjector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/) (já usei, muito bom... é o mais rápido)
- [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) (Microsoft)
- [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) (já usei, muito bom)

**Integração continua:**

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (já usei, achei bom)
- [Team City - JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/): a JetBrains é a produtora de ReSharper... precisa falar mais?

**Testes de interface:**

- [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), com .Net binding (já usei faz tempo, achava bastante fácil)
- [Selenium Toolkit for .Net](http://seleniumtoolkit.codeplex.com/)
- [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/): existe um [pacote do nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS/). O PhantomJS permite fazer testes sem precisar ter um browser instalado, e sem necessidade de mostrar janelas.

Comment: Obrigado Miguel pela resposta, uma duvida estas opções citadas, elas são alternativa para o cucumber? Gostaria de utilizar algum framework, que abre o "browser" e realiza os testes, conforme o meu plano de tes

Comment: @Tiago tem o Selenium. Inclui ele na resposta.

Comment: vocês ja utilizaram o SpecFlow? Recomendam este framework?

Comment: @Tiago Não usei o SpecFlow até o momento... mas parece que vale a pena tentar.

Answer (score 0):

Para testes de interface, tambem acrescentaria o Coded UI Tests do Visual Studio.

Pessoalmente para testes unitários eu tenho usado o NUNIT com o resharper e estou bastante satisfeito.

Indico-te mais uns quantos [IOC containers](http://www.iocbattle.com/) que podes usar com .NET. No passado usei o Ninject, mas é bastante "pesado" mudei a minha escolha para o AutoFac. Podes ate' escrever o teu [próprio](http://ayende.com/blog/2886/building-an-ioc-container-in-15-lines-of-code) IOC com poucas linhas de código se não estiveres satisfeito com o que existe.